# How can I reflect a 3 dimesional parameter's data in OPL

Tags: opl

I am willing to use a 3D parameter on my LP project. However, I cannot read the parameter's data in a proper way.
Is it possible to get the data by using Excel or by writing the parameter's values in matrix form at .dat file. Also, other potential solutions can be helpful.

```
float rt[B][P][Z]=...; //Response time of boat type b at port p to zone z
```

Answer (score 0):

well, a 3dim array is for all compbination of the 3 indeces, and excel is a 2dim table format, so on the way you started writing things you can't read a 3dim array from excel directly. Does the 3dim means that indeed you need all combinations, or some. If the later then if B/P/Z exist for some combinations, then you could use a tuple format for the triplets... 
the declaration of the tuple type is something like

```
tuple BPZ {int B; 
       float P; 
       float Z};
```

then you declare the data with this type like

```
{BPZ} myData = ...;
```

and then in the excel you have 1 table with all the triplets.

if the first (all compbinations have data), then the other way is to make each PZ 2dim arrays/table/matrix in excel B times... tedious, but doable if you don't create the data manually but programmatically = in Python you can use openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ - I've used it, it's quite good/straightforward) and then DOOPL to get the OPL/Python together (https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/blog/2018/09/26/opl-and-python/ + https://pypi.org/project/doopl/). you could use the triplets/tuple in any case, when all combinations are present but then it might be a lot of value, so it depends on the size of B*P*Z how you want to go...